# Jupyter on Azure HDInsight can't read a file on same directory

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I want to separate configuration variables from Jupyter notebook. So I thought I would put all these variables in a separate json file. I use Azure HDInsight and don't want to depend on storage account name and key to access this file, as they are config variables themselves.

So I thought storing this config json file on same directory as notebook location would solve this problem and also allow changing this config file without having to touch Python script as [it is also saved in storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-kernels#where-are-the-notebooks-stored).

However, Python can't read this file which is on same directory(see screenshots)

Notebook Home:

[image: Notebook home]

Notebook:[image: Azure Notebook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this is because of different users and permissions.

Notebook is running with user `livy` and when I run magic commands, the user is `spark`. So `pwd` magic command shows working directory as `/var/lib/jupyter` (which is very confusing) and it contains all the files displayed on notebook home.

To solve my problem at hand, I can use wasp with path (without container and storage account hostname as it is stored in default storage).

`config = spark.read.json("wasb:///HdiNotebooks/config.json")`

This way I removed container name and storage account name hard coding in spark code.

Comment: I was just about to mention that you can use `wasb:///...`. I'm glad you found it by yourself.